# Dual Citizenship travel to Cuba via America

Tags: us-citizens, dual-citizenship, dutch-citizens

This is actually a question a friend of mine had that I couldn't answer directly and really don't know the laws specifically.

If a person already has dual citizenship (specifically American and Dutch) but was born Dutch are they still required to follow travel resrictions to Cuba?

It is unlawful for an American citizen to travel to Cuba since the trade embargo without being granted permission. Most countries do not require a visa up front when traveling as an American citizen and a visa can easily be obtained upon arrival.

Of course there are ways around this rule but without bending or breaking the law of the US.

Would such a travel under a Dutch visa be detrimental to a US citizenship?

Comment: [Already asked on Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38584/travel-to-cuba-as-dual-citizen-dutch-born-dutch-us-citizen). Also a duplicate of [this other question on Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11633/travel-to-cuba-as-dual-citizen-usaother). And [please don't crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Please don't cross post questions on Stackexchange. It's far more on-topic on travel, and you received input there too.

Comment: This is being closed as a cross-posted [duplicate of a question on travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38584/travel-to-cuba-as-dual-citizen-dutch-born-dutch-us-citizen)

Comment: Am leaving it visible, but closed, so that anyone finding the info here can still find the answers.

Comment: Yes, I posted this here by accident and reposted in the Travel community where I thought it was more appropriate.